# Screen Scroll when using multiple cursors in Sublime Text

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

When I manually add multiple cursors, the ones that are just below one another, when I reach the end of the screen Sublime is not scrolling as I continue to add multiple cursors. Is there any way to enable that functionality so screen will scroll as I add more cursors so I can see how much more I need to add them.